# nuget bootstrao and jquery package loading

Tags: asp.net, nuget

i am loading the `bootstrap` and `jquery` packages from nuget:
[image]
[image]

but i get an error message in chrome console saying that

> $ sign is not defined

[image]

do i need to referense the `jquery` lib file, from the `aspx` page?

if do so, what happen when `jquery` gets updated, his file name will update too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, yes. You will need to reference the jquery file in every page you use it in. Alternatively, if you are using a _Layout page, you only need to do so once. In terms of the updating issue, your jquery file should not update automatically so you should be fine.

You could also make sure you have jquery migrate installed so that you never have deprecated or code breaking errors in your program. [jQuery Migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate)

Also consider using [jQuery CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery) rather than having the files stored locally as this can make updating and upgrading far easier

Comment: The `js` file for jquery named `jquery-3.0.0.js`, when other version will get out, and i will update it via `nuget`, wont the file name be changed too?

Comment: Yes it will and you will have to update the references in your code